# How to use count and case statement with time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, case

I'm currently working with a dataset and I'm trying to count the total number of rides during specific times, but I got stuck at some point when coding.

Just to give you context, here is a sneak peek of the data:

[image]

This is what I have so far, but I don't know what to put after the ride length min and after the THEN condition. Maybe I should try with a different column or even code it differently?

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me and find a better way to run this query.

```
SELECT
    COUNT (CASE 
              WHEN ride_length_min = '' AND (CONVERT(nvarchar(60),[started_at], 108) BETWEEN '05:00:00' AND '12:00:00')
                  THEN '' 
           END) AS MorningRides,
    COUNT (CASE 
               WHEN ride_length_min = '' AND (CONVERT(nvarchar(60),[started_at], 108) BETWEEN '12:59:59' AND  '17:00:00') 
                   THEN '' 
           END) AS AfternoonRides,
    COUNT (CASE 
               WHEN ride_length_min = '' AND (CONVERT(nvarchar(60),[started_at], 108) BETWEEN '17:59:59' AND  '21:00:00')  
                   THEN '' 
           END) AS EveningRides,
    COUNT (CASE 
               WHEN ride_length_min = '' AND (CONVERT(nvarchar(60),[started_at], 108) BETWEEN '21:59:59' AND  '4:00:00') 
                   THEN '' 
           END) AS NightRides
FROM 
    [dbo].[2022_01_divvy_tripdata]
```

Just for the record I gave it a try with the member type column because I used the two types of members as a condition, and it runs okay but that's not exactly the output I'm looking for. I would like to get the total count for Morning, afternoon, evening, and night.

```
SELECT
    COUNT (CASE 
               WHEN member_type = 'member' AND (CONVERT(nvarchar(60),[started_at], 108) BETWEEN '05:00:00' AND '12:00:00') 
                   THEN 'Morning' 
           END) AS MorningRides,
    COUNT (CASE 
               WHEN member_type = 'casual' AND (CONVERT(nvarchar(60),[started_at], 108) BETWEEN '12:59:59' AND '17:00:00') 
                   THEN 'Morning' 
           END) AS MorningRides
FROM 
    [dbo].[2022_01_divvy_tripdata]
```

Comment: What does `when ride_length_min = ''` mean? This condition doesn't make sense, especially when the sample data all shows positive integers in this column. Also your time buckets seem to go from 5 AM to noon, then a second before 1 PM to 5 PM, then a second before 6 PM to 8 PM, then a second before 10 PM to 4 AM. Does a lunchtime ride or a 4:30 AM ride not fit into any of your buckets? Please show sample data as text or a [fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle) instead of a screenshot, and show the results you want, because it will be hard for us to determine that from the queries that don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing a little bit here, but I *think* this might be what you are looking for:

```
WITH buckets(s,e,n) AS
(
  SELECT s,e,n FROM (VALUES
   ('05:00:00', '12:00:00', 'MorningRides'),
   ('12:59:59', '17:00:00', 'AfterNoonRides'),
   ('17:59:59', '21:00:00', 'EveningRides'),
   ('21:59:59', '23:59:59', 'NightRides'),
   ('00:00:00', '04:00:00', 'NightRides')
  ) AS v(s,e,n)
),
src AS
(
  SELECT member_type, n = COALESCE(b.n, 'Other') 
    FROM [dbo].[2022_01_divvy_tripdata] AS r
    LEFT OUTER JOIN buckets AS b
    ON CONVERT(time(2), r.started_at) BETWEEN b.s AND b.e
)
SELECT * FROM src
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(n) FOR n IN 
  (
    [MorningRides],[AfternoonRides],
    [EveningRides],[NightRides],[Other]
  )
) AS p;
```

Output given the sample data:

| member_type | MorningRides | AfternoonRides | EveningRides | NightRides | Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| casual | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| member | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 4 |

If you don't want to group my member type, just change `COUNT(n)` to `COUNT(member_type)`:

```
WITH buckets(s,e,n) AS
(
  SELECT s,e,n FROM (VALUES
   ('05:00:00', '12:00:00', 'MorningRides'),
   ('12:59:59', '17:00:00', 'AfterNoonRides'),
   ('17:59:59', '21:00:00', 'EveningRides'),
   ('21:59:59', '23:59:59', 'NightRides'),
   ('00:00:00', '04:00:00', 'NightRides')
  ) AS v(s,e,n)
),
src AS
(
  SELECT member_type, n = COALESCE(b.n, 'Other') 
    FROM [dbo].[2022_01_divvy_tripdata] AS r
    LEFT OUTER JOIN buckets AS b
    ON CONVERT(time(2), r.started_at) BETWEEN b.s AND b.e
)
SELECT * FROM src
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(member_type) FOR n IN 
  (
    [MorningRides],[AfternoonRides],
    [EveningRides],[NightRides],[Other]
  )
) AS p;
```

Output:

| MorningRides | AfternoonRides | EveningRides | NightRides | Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 4 |

[Working db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/aeiKnFDb) for the above two queries which, notably, don't ever try to compare date/time values by converting them to a string.

The most complicated part is splitting the range that straddles midnight into two discrete ranges (because you can't quite say `BETWEEN 10 PM and 4 AM` very easily), and I'm still not 100% happy about that.

As an aside, I don't like `BETWEEN` very much because different data types can round things differently at the edges. Better to be able to say `>= some boundary and < next boundary`. More info in the links in the `BETWEEN` section here:

- [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates)